# Equatiomatic: lmer model "subsript out of bounds"

Tags: r, equation, lme4

I am trying the equatiomatic package to plot my lmer model.

```
c1<-lmer(sqrt(co22)~t.air+t.soil+tdr+ph+TC+TN+wtd+Fe+0+(1|treatment/site), data=data)
```

However, when trying to extract the equation, I keep getting the error:

```
extract_eq(c1,wrap = TRUE, ital_vars = FALSE)

Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, v[1], v[2], value = greek_vcov) : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

But, it works fine if I convert the model to a simple linear model without random effects:

```
c1<-lm(sqrt(co22)~t.air+t.soil+tdr+ph+TC+TN+wtd+Fe+0, data=data)

extract_eq(c1,wrap = TRUE, ital_vars = FALSE)

$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{sqrt(co22)} &= \beta_{0}(\operatorname{t.air}) + \beta_{1}(\operatorname{t.soil}) + \beta_{2}(\operatorname{tdr}) + \beta_{3}(\operatorname{ph})\ + \\
&\quad \beta_{4}(\operatorname{TC}) + \beta_{5}(\operatorname{TN}) + \beta_{6}(\operatorname{wtd}) + \beta_{7}(\operatorname{Fe})\ + \\
&\quad \epsilon
\end{aligned}
$$
```

Any suggestions on how to work-around the "subscript out of bounds"-error?

Comment: Making a small assumption here, that `extract_eq` was not designed to work with mixed effect models, and that is your issue.

Comment: But apparently that got fixed: https://github.com/datalorax/equatiomatic/pull/104

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the developer of that package. It should work with `lme4::lmer()` equations. The issue here is with dropping the intercept but having it vary randomly at higher levels. See [this](https://github.com/datalorax/equatiomatic/issues/158) issue for more details.

If you have suggestions for how you would expect the equation to render, I'm open to working out a fix. But for now, `equatiomatic::extract_eq()` assumes that whatever random effects you have also have corresponding fixed effects.

Comment: Brilliant, it was indeed the issue with the intercept! Thanks for the suggestion